# Is it possible to convert a radio button into checkbox dynamically?

Tags: android, radio-button

I am developing an app which consists of multiple questions with options. Here, according to server response, a radio button should change into a checkbox dynamically when the user clicks  a button. Is this possible?

Comment: would you like to change radio to checkbox and checkbox to radio by pressing any button? or without any button event?

Comment: u can dynamically add a radio button then remove that view and add checkbox

Comment: Thanks for d reply.. I would like to change radio to checkbox with a button event @Satyaki

Comment: @Addy ok, yes it's possible . I will provide you solution. You can do this by view visible and not visibility gone. I will provide example

Comment: Thankyou Satya.. Please provide an example..

Comment: To answer your question directly, it is not possible to "convert" one type of control to another.  The solution you need is to use `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE` on two different controls, one is the radio button, the other is the check box.

Comment: post your code first. :) waht u need to do is jus include both(checkbox and radio btn) and change visibility on any action. Eg. view.setVisibity(View.Gone) etc

Comment: @Addy please check my full code and give your feedback. I have developed this code for you. So, it's just a sample to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XML layout first::

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rltRadio"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="visible">

    <RadioGroup
        android1:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android1:id="@+id/radio0"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:checked="true"
            android1:text="Option 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android1:id="@+id/radio1"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:text="Option 2" />

        <RadioButton
            android1:id="@+id/radio2"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:text="Option 3" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rltRadio"
    android:visibility="gone" >
    <CheckBox
        android1:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        android1:text="CheckBox 1" />

<CheckBox
    android1:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android1:text="CheckBox 2" />

<CheckBox
    android1:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
    android1:text="CheckBox 3" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android1:id="@+id/button1"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android1:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android1:text="Change Option" />
```

After that please add this code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TestActivity extends Activity{

    RelativeLayout rltRadio,rltCheck;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.radio_to_check);

        rltRadio=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltRadio);
        rltCheck=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                rltRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rltCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

If you follow this manner then you can able to solve your problem. Please check and give your feedback .